# How to uninstall sample data from Magento 2 using CLI?

Tags: command-line-interface, sample-data, magento2

I have installed sample data in magento 2, due to power failures of system its stop in between.
Later I saw, there were showing all categories and Products almost installed.

But at home page not seem any banner or product sliders.

I tried to install it again but it shown message associated email is already exist.

[image]

How I can re-install it  via CLI ?

Comment: You must be delete customer data from database which is install before already. so first delete customer data and try again.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I trunk a **customer_entity** table. and perform same command again. Now it showing  --URL key for specified store already exists-- Then I flushed **url_rewrite** then it working fine.

Comment: Sample data Installed successfully ?

Comment: Okey, my comments useful or not to the your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove sample data in magento 2.0.0 using cli

(this will not remove the data from the database as stated here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-sample-data-other.html)

```
bin/magento sampledata:remove
```

and for update sample data :

```
bin/magento sampledata:reset
```

Comment: it not delete entities from database

Comment: yes, the data still exist in database, how to remove completely?

Answer (score 0):

There is no CLI command to uninstall the sample data. To do it you must drop the Magento 2 database. You can use magento setup:uninstall to do that.

Be careful that sample-data is not in composer.json or sample data might install again.

Comment: Hello Steve, Thank you for your answer. If I execute setup:uninstall command, what will happened there? Is Whole database truncate ? or relevant tables will truncate ?

Comment: The database is dropped.